# concatente two chars into array of chars in each index

Tags: c, arrays

I have a string named s2 like this:'12 12 13 14' of length undefined and I want store that values into a array of chars the problem is I'm storing one by one like 1 2 1 2 and i want to store two by two like 12|12|13|14. 
This is chars because i'm extracting this strings from a file but after I'will 
change to integers.

Here is my code:

```
 while(s2[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(s2[i]==' ')
            i++;

        MEM[j]=*(s2+i);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
```

MEM is the array where i store the values

My question is How can I store into array MEM two values in each index.

Comment: You can't store two values in a single char, because i's single byte element, but you could make MEM an array of two-bytes elements and store the first char in the MSB byte and the second char in the LSB.

Comment: how can i make mem an array of two-byes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of going about this.

First, have 2 character strings:

```
char MEM[size][2];

while(s2[i]!='\0')
{
    if(s2[i]==' ')
        i++;

    MEM[j][0]=*(s2+i); // *(s2 + i) is the same as s[i]
    i++;
    MEM[j][1]=*(s2+i); // *(s2 + i) is the same as s[i]
    i++;
    j++;
}
```

Second, convert numbers to `int` type:

```
int MEM[size];

while(s2[i]!='\0')
{
    if(s2[i]==' ')
        i++;

    MEM[j]=atoi(*(s2+i));
    i+=3;
    j++;
}
```

Extra:
There is a tricky version of shifting and storing but that is little complex and is not recommended.

Comment: `*(s2+i)` is simply `s2[i]`.

Comment: I figured you knew but you may want to point that out in case the OP is mysteriously looking at the syntax wondering WTF?

Comment: is the second answer storing the number with 2 character?

Comment: It is storing it in a single variable, but yes, it should store 2 numbers in given address.